# Автоинкремент MySql - повторное использование удаленных id записей

Tags: mysql, база-данных, autoincrement

Можно ли настроить таблицу mysql так, что бы при вставке новой записи использовались id удаленных записей?
Например есть в таблицt записи с id - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, удалили запись 3. Потом вставили новую и она встала под id 3, а не под id 10.
Связей с другими таблицами нет, так нужно по логике приложения.
Есть ли готовые решение в MySql? Или писать свой скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Готового решения нет и быть не может. AUTO INCREMENT работает так, чтобы новое значение всегда было больше текущего максимального значения в таблице. Перед каждой вставкой можно запрашивать "свободное" значение чем-то вроде

```sql
SELECT (t1.id + 1) as NewID
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT t2.id 
    FROM mytable t2 
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1);
```